# multiple fragments from ONE ActionTab

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-actionbar

So I'm trying to find out if this is possible. I need to load two `fragments` into two containers in the same `activity` from a single `tab` being selected.

I found this [Android - Multiple fragments in ONE tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955181/android-multiple-fragments-in-one-tab)

but no one ever answered this question.

So here is a sample of the code and what I've tried.

**listener**

```
surveyTabListener = new TabListener<Load_Fragment>(this,
            R.id.header_fragment_container, Load_Fragment.class);
```

**onTabSelected**

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (fragment == null) {
            String fragmentName = fragmentClass.getName();
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, fragmentName);
            ft.add(fragmentContainer, fragment, fragmentName);
        } else
            ft.attach(fragment);
}
```

Now I've tried to add a second `listener` to `inflate` the 2nd `fragment` like this

```
surveyTabListener2 = new TabListener<Store_Fragment>(this, 
            R.id.store_fragment_container, Store_Fragment.class);
```

and I've also tried to use a second `if else` statement in `onTabSelected` like this

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        if (fragment == null) {
            String fragmentName = fragmentClass.getName();
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, fragmentName);
            ft.add(fragmentContainer, fragment, fragmentName);
        } else
            ft.attach(fragment);                        

        if (fragment2 == null) {
            String fragmentName2 = fragmentClass2.getName();
            fragment2 = Fragment.instantiate(activity, fragmentName2);
            ft.add(fragmentContainer2, fragment2, fragmentName2);
        } else
            ft.attach(fragment2);

    }
```

Neither work, I either get a `NPE (null pointer)` or absolutely nothing happens, but I get no errors.

This seems like something that should be done fairly often but I can't seem to figure it out.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your problem. When you say "I need to load two fragments into two containers" do you mean each container will have two fragments or do you mean you will have two containers each having one fragment?

Comment: @Squonk I need to inflate 2 seperate containers with 1 fragment each (the fragments are individual, it is not the same fragment). They must be inflated simultaneously by pressing 1 tab. These are default fragment layouts I want to inflate. The purpose is so that if the user goes from Tab "A" to Tab "B" the two fragments will be different, thus the UI will change.

Comment: You're not calling `commit()` on your `FragmentTransaction`. Example... `ft.add(fragmentContainer, fragment, fragmentName).commit();` - try it and see what happens.

Comment: @IrishWhiskey surveyTabListener what type of object can you explain further more please .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It dawned on me that I was going about this the wrong way. I figured out a way to do exactly what I was looking for and it was fairly simple. If anyone else has this problem here is the solution.

```
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        //get the name of the tab currently selected
        String name = (String) tab.getText().toString();

        // compare it to the tab you  would like to do something with        
        if (name == "Assets") {
            //load the 1st fragment
            fragment = new Store_Fragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.store_fragment_container, fragment).commit();

            //load the 2nd fragment
            fragment2 = new Load_Fragment();
            getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setCustomAnimations(android.R.animator.fade_in,
                            android.R.animator.fade_out)
                    .replace(R.id.header_fragment_container, fragment2).commit();
        }
```

...and that's it. I hope this helps others.

Comment: can you explain replace(R.id.store_fragment_container, fragment) 's what is store_fragment_container please

Answer (score 2):

You need to use an empty fragment as a container for your two fragments, I'm gonna post some code to show you how I dit it.

That's the fragment container:

```
public static class FragmentInsideContainer extends Fragment {

        ListView mainListView;
        ArrayAdapter<Producer> listAdapter;
        TextView inputSearch;
        static FragmentInsideContainer containerReference;
        String idProd;

        public FragmentInsideContainer() {

        }

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layoutcontaineprod, container, false);

            FragmentInsideContainer.containerReference = this;

            FragmentDetailProd fragmentDetailProd = new FragmentDetailProd();
            FragmentDetailProd.id = this.idProd;

            DummySectionFragment2.currentDetailProdFragment = fragmentDetailProd;

            FragmentListWine fragmentListWine = new FragmentListWine();
            fragmentListWine.id = this.idProd;

            DummySectionFragment2.currentListWineFragment = fragmentListWine;

            FragmentInsideContainer.containerReference.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.containerDetail, fragmentDetailProd).commit();
            FragmentInsideContainer.containerReference.getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();
            FragmentInsideContainer.containerReference.getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.containerDetail, fragmentListWine).commit();
            FragmentInsideContainer.containerReference.getChildFragmentManager().executePendingTransactions();

            return rootView;
        }
```

Comment: I've always been told "nested" fragments are bad or won't work. I'm interested to see how you made this happen

Comment: I dont know if it's a good solution but that's the only way it seemed to worked for me. Tell me if you need more code or  the xml files. Hope this helps

Comment: I see what you're talking about, but I don't think you fully understand what I'm asking. I know how to inflate two fragments at the same time. However I don't understand how to do it from an `ActionBar` `Tab`. If this was done using an `ActionBar` `Tab` please post the `listener` code and/or the `onTabSelected` code.

Comment: I use an action bar with a swipe navigation and my onTabSelected is public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction ft) {
     mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
 }
But my inside container is inside the fragment i set with my viewpager

Comment: I found my answer from just taking a break and rethinking it. It's posted. I'll upvote yours for effort though

Comment: Ok i'm glad you resolved your problem and thanks for the upvote