# How to open multiple child fragment inside action bar tabs with swipe gesture

Tags: android-fragments, tabs, android-actionbar, swipe-gesture, android-nested-fragment

i want to open multiple child fragment inside each action bar tab with swipe feature on tabs.
what i have done so far is that i have created action bar tabs with swipe gesture to change tab but i cant open child fragment inside each tab.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

i found an answer in [Android - Multiple fragments in ONE tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12955181/android-multiple-fragments-in-one-tab)

in the last answer there is this [link](http://tausiq.wordpress.com/2014/06/06/android-multiple-fragments-stack-in-each-viewpager-tab/)

i hope it my by useful for you